# How to add many files with silverstripe uploadfield

Tags: php, web, silverstripe

**Hello everyone**,

I'm trying to add more than 1 file to my uploadfield with this code ->

```
class FileDo extends File {

    static $has_one = array(
        'DocumentsFile' => 'DocumentsFile',

    );
}


class DocumentsFile extends DataObject {


    static $has_one = array(
        'DocumentPageAcces1' => 'DocumentPageAcces1'
    );
    static $has_many = array(
        'Files' => 'FileDo'
    );


    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->removeByName('DocumentPageAcces1ID');


         return $fields;
    }

    public function onBeforeWrite() {
        parent::onBeforeWrite();
        $page = DataObject::get_one('DocumentPageAcces1');
        if($page) {
             $this->DocumentPageAcces1ID = $page->ID;
        }
    }

}




class DocumentPageAcces1 extends Page {


     static $has_many = array(
        'DocumentsFiles' => 'DocumentsFile',
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();


    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextareaField('DocumentsIntro_en', "Document Introduction"));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextareaField('PublicationsIntro_en', "Publication Introduction"));


    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.FR', new TextareaField('DocumentsIntro_fr', "Document Introduction"));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.FR', new TextareaField('PublicationsIntro_fr', "Publication Introduction"));


    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.NL', new TextareaField('DocumentsIntro_nl', "Document Introduction"));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.NL', new TextareaField('PublicationsIntro_nl', "Publication Introduction"));


     $upload = new UploadField(
        'DocumentsFile',  
        'Document',  
        $this->DocumentsFiles()
    ); 

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.DocumentsFile',  $upload);

    $fields->removeByName('Content'); 
    $fields->removeByName('Metadata'); 



    return $fields;
} 

}
class DocumentPageAcces1_Controller extends Page_Controller {

}
```

So to make it clear: i'm trying to add some DocumentFile in my DocumentPageAcces1. When i execute this code, i have in my DocumentPageAcces1 the tab DocumentsFiles and in this tab i have the uploadfield.

THE PROBLEM is that the uploadfield doesn't want to keep my file so when i chose some file, i click OK in my finder and nothing happens......Could anyone help me?

Thanks Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours I found a solution, maybe it's not the best one but it works for me ->

I created a class that extends the File class for each document type i need so I have for example

```
class DocumentFileDo extends File {
    static $has_one = array(
        'DocumentPageAcces1' => 'DocumentPageAcces1'
    );
}
```

In my DocumentPageAcces1.php I have a has_many relationship like this :

```
static $has_many = array(
    'DocumentFileDos' => 'DocumentFileDo',
);
```

And I the getCMSFields function I have :

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Document', new UploadField('DocumentFileDos'));
```

It works well, you can add many file with just a has_many relationship and an UploadField. But it's not the best i think if you have a hundred different documents type..

PS: With UploadField you can drag and drop files but this function which works well on Chrome does not on Firefox!

Answer (score 0):

`UploadField` isn't made to work with `DataObjects` but like you found with `File` or it's subclasses.

Although in your case, I don't think you need a subclass, so you could just remove your `DocumentFileDo` class that extend `File` and use this in your *DocumentPageAcces1.php*

```
static $has_many = array(
    'DocumentFiles' => 'File',
);
```

In the case you want to have more control/details on the files you upload (i.e. add descriptions, titles etc...), in that case you can create a `DataObject` that has a $has_one relation to a `File` and then use that `DataObject` in the relation on your page with a `GridField`:

**DocumentFile.php**

```
class DocumentFile extend DataObject
{
    static $db = array(
        'Description' => 'HTMLText'
    );

    static $has_one = array(
        'File' => 'File'
    );
}
```

**DocumentPageAcces1.php**

```
static $has_many = array(
    'DocumentFiles' => 'DocumentFile'
);

function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $c = new GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor();
    $f = new GridField('Documents', 'DocumentFiles', $this->DocumentFiles(), $c);
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Documents', $f);

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually your solution is fine if i only have one type of document. But if i need to add some others, i need to create DataObject else Silverstripe links both files.

Comment: not sure I actually understand what you mean? Do you want to link many files to one page? All of class File or subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with the same thing. SilverStripe even has a (faulty*) [developer guide](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/forms/field_types/uploadfield/) on this matter (though it took me hours to find it) … Anyway, I found a solution. (assuming SilverStripe 4)

*mysite/page/MyCustomPage.php*

```
class MyCustomPage extends Page
{
    private static $many_many = array(
       'DocumentFiles' => File::class
    );

    public function getCMSFields(){

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main',
            UploadField::create('DocumentFiles', 'My Documents')
        );

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

*mysite/extensions/DocumentFileExtension.php*

```
class DocumentFileExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'DocumentContainers' => MyCustomPage::class
    );

    // I actually don't know the purpose of the name "DocumentContainers"
    // ("Galleries" in the guide); it is never referenced again.
}
```

*mysite/_config/app.yml*

```
SilverStripe\Assets\File:
    extensions:
        - DocumentFileExtension
```

*themes/mytheme/templates/Layout/MyCustomPage.ss*

```
<% loop $DocumentFiles %>
    $Link
<% end_loop %>
```

You basically extend the native `File` class into a custom version of it, and "suddenly" the unchanged UploadField (that also does the same for single files) now allows multiple files; complete with a GUI and everything.

Hope this works for you.

---

* They keep using `'Foo' => 'Bar'` all over their official documentation pages instead of `'Foo' => Bar::class`, which you have to use in ss4 in order to avoid an Exception:

`Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: many_many relation SilverStripe\Blog\Model\BlogPost.DownloadFiles references class File which doesn't exist`